# Can you pre-populate an iPhone Apps Caches or Document Directory with data in XCode?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have an iPhone application that downloads images into the Caches directory on an as needed basis. However, I'd like to provide a portion of those images pre-cached. Is there a way through XCode to define a "Library/Caches" folder that will copy into the Library/Caches folder found in The Application home directory on the iPhone - so I can build them in at build time? Or do I need to put them in as a resource, and then have my app copy them to the Cache on start?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to copy them from your app bundle to the caches on first run startup.